# Extraction of images within a bounding box using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

Below is a snippet from the Tensorflow Object Detection API sample that I am trying to change.

I was trying to extract the image enclosed in the bounding box, but I'm unable to do so using the Tensorflow Detection API. Please suggest.

```
    while True:

        frame = cv2.imread(cap)

        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        expanded_frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_c) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: expanded_frame})

        # Visualization of the detection
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=1,
            min_score_thresh=0.40)

        cv2.imshow('Detection', frame)
        filename = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\Face Detected\Detected.png'
        cv2.imwrite(filename,frame)  
        fps.update()
        

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            fps.stop()
            break

    print("Fps: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))
    fps.update()
    cap.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You can the dimensions of the boxes using

```
true_boxes = boxes[0][scores[0] > min_score_thresh]

for i in range(true_boxes.shape[0]):
    ymin = true_boxes[i,0]*height
    xmin = true_boxes[i,1]*width
    ymax = true_boxes[i,2]*height
    xmax = true_boxes[i,3]*width
    print ("Top left")
    print (xmin,ymin,)
    print ("Bottom right")
    print (xmax,ymax)
```

And can crop the images using

```
cropped_img = image.crop((x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max))
```

For more details please refer to this [link](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/saving-the-predicted-images-of-bounding-boxes-tensorflow-object-detection-api/2085). Thank You.